# fetch get request is failing to get resource

Tags: javascript, fetch

when I try this url in the browser, I get a success.
But when I try it with fetch, the request never gets to the server.

```
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/hey";

        let params = {
            method: "GET",         
        };
        fetch(url, params)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("serverTestButton", res);
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                console.log("error", e);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers will strict **cors** requests originated from `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` APIs. Normally, Browsers will send a preflight requests to check if the server accepts requests from a cross origin document. To enable your server to accept **cors** requests you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or use a library like `cors` if you are using express.js. The document has a different origin in case it has a different **port**, **url** or a **protocol**.

Answer (score 0):

The fetch specification differs from `jQuery.ajax()` in the following significant ways:

- The Promise returned from `fetch()` won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.
- `fetch()` won’t send cross-origin cookies unless you set the credentials init option.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch